# Sys.argv no output

Tags: python

I'm trying to make this code work with sys.argv but it's not showing
anything on the output. The user enters a value and then it prints the key.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

v = sys.argv[1:]

d={1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'a', 5:'d', 6:'e', 7:'a', 8:'b'}

for key, value in d.items():
    if value == v: 
        print(key, '', end='')
```

Comment: And how did you start this script? I'm guessing you did it without passing any command line arguments...?

Comment: from the cmd, just entered the file name and the argument.

Comment: `v` is a list, `value` is a string. `if value == v:` will never be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're having a `type` issue

```
v = sys.argv[1:] #  v is a list here, even if its a single item or empty
```

the values in `d` are not lists so they don't match
if you change this line:

```
if value == v:
```

into:

```
if value in v:
```

it will work. what it does is check if your value is contained in the list

Comment: Thank you, can you help me again?

`word = sys.argv[1:]
print(Counter(word).most_common(len(word)))`
Why is there no output when I run this code? I can't get this..

Comment: without knowing the contents of word that would be difficult, try printing `word` before you call Counter...  also, dont forget that `word` is a list here so passing `len(word)` to most_common is that same as passing nothing

Comment: The `word` is just a string. The output should print all the letters and how often they are in the string.     `word = "Hello"` - when passed at sys.argv. Output should be: `[('l', 2), ('h', 1), ('e', 1), ('o', 1)]`

Comment: if you are doing `word = sys.argv[1:] ` then word is most definitely a `list` and not a `string` if you want the first parameter you passwed the program use `word = sys.argv[1]`

Comment: @okdenyou code should still work though, are you SURE `word` isn't empty? also, what do you mean by "no output"? it should at least print `[]`

Comment: I did and it says "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Ill explain how I test it. I open cmd and I cd to the python file, then type the file name + the string. Like this: file.py hello. And yes, it prints `[]`

Comment: please print `sys.argv`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190202/discussion-between-okden-and-nullman).

Answer (score 0):

```
v = sys.argv[1:]
```

sets `v` to a list of all the command line arguments. If you just want the first argument, it should be:

```
v = sys.argv[1]
```